# PG::ConnectionBad - could not connect to server: Connection refused on Mac OS X

Tags: ruby-on-rails, database, postgresql, rubygems

After installing the needed `ruby` version with: `rvm install 2.7.1` and installing all the gems,
I was planning to create the db with `rails db:create` but I am getting this error:

```
could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5442?
Couldn't create 'development' database. Please check the configuration.
rails aborted!
PG::ConnectionBad: could not connect to server: Connection refused
  Is the server running on host "127.0.0.1" and accepting
  TCP/IP connections on port 5442?
```

My `database.yml`

```
default: &default
  adapter: postgresql
  pool: <%= ENV.fetch("RAILS_MAX_THREADS") { 15 } %>
  host: <%= ENV.fetch("DATABASE_HOST") { '127.0.0.1' } %>

development:
  <<: *default
  database: development

test:
  <<: *default
  database: test

production:
  <<: *default
  database: production
```

Seems that it's related to postgres.
It's version is: `postgres (postgreSQL) 12.4`

`pg` gem version is `1.2.3`

Restarting the `postgresql` didn't helped

Comment: Is the Postgres server on same machine as Ruby app?  If not is there a firewall between them? The default port for Postgres is `5432`, so have you tried that? OS and version? Can you use `psql` to connect to server using the same connection parameters? Do you multiple instances of Postgres running and have you verified they are all running?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It appeared that I needed to create a new PostgreSQL database cluster.
First you need to remove the `postgres` dir in the `/usr/local/var/`

you can use this code - `cd /usr/local/var/ && rm -rf postgres`

after that - create the new `postgres` folder `mkdir postgres` (inside `/usr/local/var`)

and initialise the creation of the new PostgreSQL database cluster with -

`cd && initdb --locale=C -E UTF-8 /usr/local/var/postgres`

The last thing, restart the postgres - `brew services restart postgresql`